# How to use read <<< in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to run this code in bash but I can't. Bash doesn't run it! it's like it's waiting for me to continue and it doesn't think that my command is done! But I'm already done! I know that the problem is with read <<<. so how can I fix it?

**Here is my code:**

```
for f in `ls *| head -100`; do a=$(file "$f" | grep -Po ", \K\d+x\d+"`);
> IFS="x";
> read x y <<< "$a";
> done;
> 
>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `<<<` and everything to do with the unbalanced contexts. Run it through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds.

Comment: You c/p the hanging backtick ` from that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48389559/1). :)

Comment: (...though there are also serious problems with making programmatic use of `ls`; much safer to `files=( * ); for f in "${files[@]:0:100}"; do` to iterate over the first hundred files; see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)).

Comment: @randomir god damn it lol!:)) actually I had another issue with `read <<<` before that's why I thought the problem was with that! You can see that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992359/how-to-use-read-ra-inline)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you so much for your great helpful comment:)

Comment: I hope that was heartfelt as opposed to sarcastic -- it's so hard to tell sometimes. :) -- btw, consider `IFS=x read x y <<<"$a"` all on one line -- that way `IFS` is only changed for the one `read` command, rather than for all future commands in the script.

Comment: Of course That was heartfelt! And thanks a lot for your second helpful comment also :D Such a pity I can't send you a friend request here! lol;-) BTW you have a cool profile picture:P

Comment: Thank you -- it was designed by my wife's best friend, and has both of our initials embedded (CD / TLH); I had it made into a stamp for sealing envelopes with wax. Yours is visually interesting and unique as well. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So You even thought me some nice lessons of romance as well! You won't believe it but it's actually my birthday today:)) lol!

Answer (score 1):

You have a superfluous backtick:

```
for f in `ls *| head -100`; do a=$(file "$f" | grep -Po ", \K\d+x\d+"`);
#                                                           Here  ---^
IFS="x";
read x y <<< "$a";
done;
```

[ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) helpfully points this out. Voting to close as a simple typographical error.